# ASP .NET MVC 5 model binding of byte[] produces null value with ajax GET reqest

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate a variable for the following method in my Controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(byte[] status, byte type)
```

My problem is that I keep getting - ***null*** - for this parameter when making an AJAX call using jQuery.

The byte[] '*status*' is intended to serve as a collection of values to compare records in a DB query, so as to return all the record that match one or more condition (status: 0=pending, 1=Completed etc.)

**SIDE NOTE**: The table wherein these records are stored has the '*status*' and '*type*' columns defined as a ***tinyint*** ... thus POCO classes are generated with these properties defined as byte :/

This is the jQuery AJAX call

`$.get(
"/Activity/Index", 
$.param({ type: $actiontype, status: $status }),
function (response) { $('#ActivitySubIndex').html(response) }
)`

which produces a GET request like this

```
http://localhost:8084/Activity/Index?type=0&status[]=0&status[]=1&status[]=2
```

**SO** ...

when I change the way jQuery preps the data being sent to the server by specifying the " *traditional* " flag on the $.param function like so

`$.param({ type: $actiontype, status: $status }, true)`

it produces a request like this

```
http://localhost:8084/Activity/Index?type=0&status=0&status=1&status=2
```

**BUT** ...now I get an error from the server saying

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Not too sure about that ... so now I'm left with figuring out how model binding (or whatever MVC does behind the scenes) is falling over.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC Model binding seems to want you to define the method as follows.

```
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<byte> status, byte type)
```

Prepping the jQuery AJAX function to send the parameters with the "traditional" flag set to true was also required.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this function that i created:

```
function ParamsBuilder(obj, listname, firstParam) {
    // obj : [ { Name = "Id", Value = "2" }, { Name = "Name", Value = "A" }, { Name = "Id", Value = "3" }, { Name = "Name", Value = "B" }, { Name = "Id", Value = "4" }, { Name = "Name", Value = "Z" }, ]
    // obj : [ { Value = "2" }, { Value = "3" }, { Value = "4" } ]
    // obj : [ 2, 3, 4 ]
    // listname: Name of the parameter like "/Controller/Action/param" where param is a list/collection/array
    // firstParam: if is the first param or not, to apply ? or &

    var str = "";
    $(obj).each(function (idx, element) {
        if (element.Name != null && element.Name != "" && element.Name != undefined) {
            str += "&" + listname + "[" + idx + "]." + element.Name + "=" + element.Value;
        }
        else if (element.Value != null && element.Value != "" && element.Value != Value) {
            str += "&" + listname + "[" + idx + "]=" + element.Value;
        }
        else {
            str += "&" + listname + "[" + idx + "]=" + element;
        }
    });

    if (firstParam) {
        str = "?" + str.substring(1);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Just call it like this:

```
var statusObj = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var url = "/Activity/Index?type=0" + ParamsBuilder(statusObj, "status", false);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zkz1730q/)